# Markdown preview on website

Tags: markdown

Can I preview .md files on web that I will create? Or I must convert .md to .html file?
Because I want to write in markdown, and upload article without any converting. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Well markdown is not part of the html standard so you would need a program to parse the markdown, which do exist. So it is possible.
2. You can preview the markdown you are writing on a website like [stackedit.](https://stackedit.io/) I use [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) to convert my markdown files into html files and upload them that way. It is not very difficult.

Comment: I found a extension to my text editor which is converting markdown files to html files. Thank you for feedback.

Comment: Of course, it is Sublime Text 2 and Markdown Preview plugin, which includes build system :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a node module which can convert markdown files to html files.

**In a project**

```
Install npm install -D markdown-folder-to-html
Add docs to npm scripts {"scripts": {"docs": "markdown-folder-to-html"}}
npm run docs and open _docs/index.html
```

**Globally**

```
Install npm install -g markdown-folder-to-html
cd markdown-folder-to-html/ and open _docs/index.html
```

**Example:**

```
mkdir -p docs
Add some docs echo "**Banana**" > docs/banana.md
Add some docs echo "**Apple**" > docs/index.md

markdown-folder-to-html docs/  // it will create _docs folder which contains html preview of markdown
```

Installation guide: https://chimeces.com/markdown-folder-to-html/